# How would I read my player and weapons positions from a text file. I want when the game starts to automatically load them in

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

I have a text file with four lines called position that already has the positions written and split by commas.

I try to run my code, but I get an error on `dataline.ReadLine(dataline)` saying:

> Type ////`string' does not contain a definition for `ReadLine' and no extensiomethod `//ReadLine' of type `string' could be found (are you missing a using directive //or an assembly reference?)

```
using UnityEngine;
using System.Collections;
using System.IO;
public class InitializeLevel : MonoBehaviour
{
    private StreamReader sr;
    public string filename;

    void LoadPositions(string filename)
    {
//Using a try catch block.
        try
        {
            sr = new StreamReader(Application.dataPath + "/" + filename);
            string dataline = "";
            while (dataline != null)
            {
               dataline.ReadLine(dataline);
                string[] values = dataline.Split(',');
                Vector3 pos = Vector3.zero;
                pos.x = float.Parse(values[1]);
                pos.y = float.Parse(values[2]);
                pos.z = float.Parse(values[3]);

                GameObject Player = (GameObject)Instantiate(Resources.Load(values[0]));
                Player.transform.position = pos;
            }
        }
        catch (IOException e)
        {
            Debug.Log(e.Message);
        }
        finally
        {
            if (sr != null)
                sr.Close();
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: It is the StreamReader that reads the file. and assign the return to a string

Comment: Don't hide your question inside comments in the code.  As Steve said, it is the StreamReader that reads the file. You want to do `while ((dataline = sr.ReadLine()) != null)`, and remove this line: `dataline.ReadLine(dataline);`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As already said in the comments, the right way to do this is

```
        sr = new StreamReader(Application.dataPath + "/" + filename);
        string dataline = "";
        while ((dataline = sr.ReadLine()) != null)
        {
            string[] values = dataline.Split(',');
            Vector3 pos = Vector3.zero;
            pos.x = float.Parse(values[1]);
            pos.y = float.Parse(values[2]);
            pos.z = float.Parse(values[3]);

            GameObject Player = (GameObject)Instantiate(Resources.Load(values[0]));
            Player.transform.position = pos;
        }
```